# Añadir un valor a cada array dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript, typescript

estoy tratando de ingresar esta variable que trae diferentes valores dentro de cada array en un objeto

la variable sum me trae estos valores: `235`, `100`, `474`, `351`, `6804`, asi es el objeto
[image: objeto]

Y el objeto me trae el ultimo valor de la variable `this.sum` y queda de esta manera

[image: objeto2]

y estoy tratando de que por cada array dentro del objeto se guarde la variable suma de la siguiente manera

```
[
 {
   id:202,..., sum_msg_send:235
 },
      {
   id:223,..., sum_msg_send:100
 },
      {
   id:273,..., sum_msg_send:474
 },
      {
   id:471,..., sum_msg_send:351
 },
      {
   id:788,..., sum_msg_send:6804
 },
]
```

este es el codigo que tengo:

```
this.groups = rsp['cards'];
// console.log(typeof rsp);
 for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(this.groups).length; index++) {
  const element = this.groups[index];
  // console.log(element);
  this.apiSvc.receiveMessages(element.id).subscribe((rsp: any) =>{
   // console.log(rsp);
   const reducer = (acc, value) => acc + parseInt(value.total_msg_send);
   this.sum = rsp.reduce(reducer, 0);
   // console.log(sum);
   console.log(this.sum);
   this.groups.forEach(v => {v.sum_msg_send = this.sum;});
                    
                    
  });
                
 }
 console.log(this.groups);
```

Comment: Hola, qué problema estás teniendo con tu código?

Comment: Hola, disculpa la tardanza, el codigo me esta añadiendo a los array dentro del objeto ese valor pero me lo esta añadiendo con el ultimo valor de la variable `this.sum`, osea que en todos los array me esta poniendo  `sum_msg_send:6804`

Comment: Eso agrégalo a la pregunta por favor. Te invito a leer cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Ok, gracias Andres